# How to get dictionary inside list and retrive specific values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to get dictionaries inside list and get specific values from them.

here is list that contain actual data:

```
[[{'confidence': 0.9655525279517, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'firefox'}],

[{'confidence': 0.97317936846366, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'open'}], 

[{'confidence': 0.98969319754083, 'value': 'app'}]]
```

what i want is:
get value from every dictionary like:

```
 value :'firefox'

 value : 'open'

 value : 'app'
```

How i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mylist = [[{'confidence': 0.9655525279517, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'firefox'}], [{'confidence': 0.97317936846366, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'open'}], [{'confidence': 0.98969319754083, 'value': 'app'}]]

for i in range(len(Mylist)):
    Values = Mylist[i][0]['value']
    print(Values)
```

in this way you can accomplish it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. got correct output. But rather than 'D' it supposed to be Mylist.

Comment: Yeah thats right :) because i write it firstly with D then i changed it to Mylist.

Comment: You can assign your question as answered so it won't stay opend.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over each list, and extract what you need:

```
>>> lst = [[{'confidence': 0.9655525279517, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'firefox'}], [{'confidence': 0.97317936846366, 'type': 'value', 'value': 'open'}], [{'confidence': 0.98969319754083, 'value': 'app'}]]

>>> print([x[0]['value'] for x in lst])
['firefox', 'open', 'app']
```